I2P - No Such Host is Known
I'm trying to build a web browser on top of I2P called "Pheremone" using C#/.NET & I2P.NET. The heart of a web browser is retrieving and rendering HTML/CSS or WebGL and running JavaScript or WASM. However, while trying to write the code to retrieve an I2P URL, I ran into an issue. Every I2P website (eepsite) I've tried my code with isn't working. This code is almost verbatim from the SampleProject provided alongside I2P.NET, combined with the .NET HTTPClient API.
using I2PNet;
using System.Net;

var i2pclient = new I2PSession(samPort: 7656);
await i2pclient.InitializeAsync();

var handler = new HttpClientHandler
{
    Proxy = i2pclient as IWebProxy,
    UseProxy = true,
};

var client = new HttpClient(handler);
var html = await client.GetStringAsync("http://isitup.i2p");

Console.Write(html);

I tried this code with various eepsites in place of "http://isitup.i2p" and double, triple, and quadruple checked that I2P was, indeed, working. Despite that, I always got errors along these lines.
HELLO REPLY RESULT=OK VERSION=3.3
> SESSION CREATE STYLE=STREAM ID=1450712372 DESTINATION=TRANSIENT
SESSION STATUS RESULT=OK DESTINATION=vDEIQ3Ggx98MGC1iD68nthx2-w47IS0VHoSRpIDt5SO8MQhDcaDH3wwYLWIPrye2HHb7DjshLRUehJGkgO3lI7wxCENxoMffDBgtYg-vJ7YcdvsOOyEtFR6EkaSA7eUjvDEIQ3Ggx98MGC1iD68nthx2-w47IS0VHoSRpIDt5SO8MQhDcaDH3wwYLWIPrye2HHb7DjshLRUehJGkgO3lI7wxCENxoMffDBgtYg-vJ7YcdvsOOyEtFR6EkaSA7eUjvDEIQ3Ggx98MGC1iD68nthx2-w47IS0VHoSRpIDt5SO8MQhDcaDH3wwYLWIPrye2HHb7DjshLRUehJGkgO3lI3I3mDSgehQcWlEyR7Uuyy-KgVs44LKuOEYOPbnhfsgrf1S~B-sPrpvHcJntfihfcQs3mfoLasAHgYVY96hiea7PHuy4Hmm25E-CyXCG0adVBup3tKs9ogVPNhEDaaUfe523VJzCwNWdnQHuapxp~JtHSHDoI0NapRZBryXELkxLAAAAb9n38OmeWuC0YuX68qQ7A6a6c41x-rN2-XDuRiYIZ6MIrgLUgQTmnp-TUDbh3YoAHYWfo7gG2OTUlsK57Qf5rDAe0GwxyTIzKFdXDsUVE9-b8XBoEClGfwIcXpx5MGTqwCHwQHkGNnWK3o5onpRnOgzZ7JFtX81n-AI4m5nzNKZmmcPpJWSCcOAqarvENsOx6MCF3StajRxxtRR00cN6XjMI2drvjXwH9MLuS5AAwmH5w0FFP~HD4VN2fTS1aqw6v9HxHHJk1zTHv0kQ8pYr77Sri6e2PvvtY9Dl3RQkJPjOUejRh8UMAASAviUBPZ6Iy3V2hoMFqNqtdD5~VQok24pTplmy0KlcY8WkTtkpbdG5aRms
Unhandled exception. System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: No such host is known. (isitup.i2p:80)
 ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (11001): No such host is known.
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.ThrowException(SocketError error, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.System.Threading.Tasks.Sources.IValueTaskSource.GetResult(Int16 token)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.<ConnectAsync>g__WaitForConnectWithCancellation|285_0(AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs saea, ValueTask connectTask, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectToTcpHostAsync(String host, Int32 port, HttpRequestMessage initialRequest, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectToTcpHostAsync(String host, Int32 port, HttpRequestMessage initialRequest, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.AddHttp11ConnectionAsync(QueueItem queueItem)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSourceWithCancellation`1.WaitWithCancellationAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)

